# document.getElementById JS HTML CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get my forms NOT TO reset. I am making a `<input type="password" />` and whenever I click the button to submit the password, and they get it wrong, I need there to be something that shows that it is incorrect. It works, but only for a split second. Can you help me?

```js
function desktop() {

  var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  if (pass == "555") {
    alert("Welcome;")
  } else {
    document.getElementById("wrg").innerHTML = "Incorrect Password";

  }

}
```

```css
#pass {
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#user {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 220px;
}

#wrg {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <center>
    <h1 id="user">User</h1>
    <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder=" Password" /><br>
    <button onclick="desktop()" id="pass">Sign In</button>
    <p id="wrg"></p>
  </center>
</form>
```

Comment: **WHY** are you using `Javascript` for authentication ?!?!?!?!

Comment: @Zak, could be just to learn the basics. We've all done something like this before I'm sure.

Comment: Your page is refreshed, when button is clicked -> form is submitted... Quick fix:  <button type="button"  onclick="desktop()" id="pass">Sign In</button> Default type is 'submit', when there is no type attribute set...

Answer (score 2):

The button ends up submitting the form, which causes the window to refresh because there's no `action` attribute on the form.

You can prevent this by either making the button `type="button"` (rather than the default `submit`), using `event.preventDefault()`, or by returning false, as below.  (But as noted in comments below, `return false` may not be the best approach: it's easy to forget to include the `return` in both the function and the `onclick` attribute, without which the form will submit anyway.  `event.preventDefault` is the most explicit and therefore probably best way to handle this.)

```js
function desktop() {
  var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  if (pass == "555") {
    alert("Welcome;")
  } else {
    document.getElementById("wrg").innerHTML = "Incorrect Password";
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
#pass {
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#user {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  /*margin-top: 220px;*/
}
```

```html
<form>
  <center>
    <h1 id="user">User</h1>
    <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder=" Password" /><br>
    <button onclick="return desktop()">Sign In</button>
    <p id="wrg"></p>
  </center>
</form>
```

(You do have duplicate `pass` IDs, which should be unique, and of course clientside authentication as done here isn't the least bit secure, but neither of those issues is directly relevant to your question.  `getElementById` winds up returning the first matching element, which happens to be the one you wanted.)

Comment: Careful with using `return false` in a click handler. It will only work if you hook up the handler with `onclick="return desktop()"`. [If you use `onclick="desktop()"`, or in a proper `button.addEventListener` handler, it does nothing.](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html) `event.preventDefault()` is more explicit and doesn't act weird.

Comment: Thank YOU! And yes, I am just a coder getting started.

Comment: @AuxTaco that's a good point, I'll edit the answer to include that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using duplicate IDs for your button and input elements: `pass`.

Also, it would be easier to just add an event listener to the Sign In button and capture that event inside your function.

```
document.getElementById("pass").addEventListener('click', desktop);

function desktop(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  if (pass == "555") {
    alert("Welcome;");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("wrg").innerHTML = "Incorrect Password";
  }
}
```

If you do it this way, remember to remove the onclick attribute from the button.

Comment: You need to add what event is supposed to trigger the event listener: `.addEventListener('click', desktop)`